# Can't open a SAS program from the context menu

Tags: sas

When I try to open a SAS program from the context menu, I come across the following error. However, I am able to open the program in SAS via "File > Open Program". I have changed the initial system folder by editing "sasv9.cfg". But this doesn't help.

The error message seems to indicate that SAS attempts to write the log to the "System32"
folder, which the current user profile doesn't have access to. I'm running this from a corporate computer.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks you tried to RUN the program instead of just OPEN it.  That is why it tried to create a .log file.  If you have the normal file associations installed then you should see many more choices available for .sas files.

[image]

Comment: You are right. When I click "See more options", I can open the SAS file by picking an option from the menu that pops up, like the one you posted. Thanks a lot.